# Dynamically managing sheets in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which act as a template.

Currently, sheet3 to sheet12 is storing a table with same template. The information of my sheet3 to sheet12 is statically stored inside a dictionary like below (Of course I could use a loop here but for simplicity)

```
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet3.Range("F5").Value, 3
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet4.Range("F5").Value, 4
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet5.Range("F5").Value, 5
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet6.Range("F5").Value, 6
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet7.Range("F5").Value, 7
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet8.Range("F5").Value, 8
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet9.Range("F5").Value, 9
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet10.Range("F5").Value, 10
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet11.Range("F5").Value, 11
Value2SheetNo.Add Sheet12.Range("F5").Value, 12
```

However, since the workbook is a template, there are times where I only need 5 tables (hence only from sheet3 to sheet7 is needed, sheet8 to sheet12 would be deleted). 
How could I cater for condition like this without modifying the code underlying?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling your code? You can put the above code in a loop using a variable `For i = 1 to ShtNo` and then call it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If the code is using Worksheet Code Names like your example appears to, then the answer is no, you can't really cater for the condition of missing sheets without modifying the code to not use worksheet code names.  (It might work if all code referencing Sheet12 runs *before* Sheet12 gets deleted, but if any of it needs to run *after*, then you need to change the code.)

If you want suggestions on how to change the code, let me know.